# Is it possible to emulate a smartphone with multiple back cameras with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, device-emulation

Does anybody know if you can emulate a smartphone with multiple back cameras with Android Studio?

I am new to AS and the answers that I found googling (i.e. multi-camera API) don't seem to solve the problem I'm having (or maybe they do, but I fail to see the connection).

The project is a video chat web app (sockets and stuff), so I need to get the info about cameras and mics. Recently I received feedback that the app happens to struggle with smartphones that have multiple back cameras (for example, Samsung A41). Looks as if I fail to get their proper ids and labels (device list is full of blanks / empty strings).

I don't have such a device on me, nor does anybody around me, and as it is NOT a mobile app I can't just run it with AS in debug mode (right?). So I was planning on emulating one to test the app and get rid of the bug. Please, share any thoughts!

Comment: Please share more details here, what you have tried and so on. `and as it is NOT a mobile app`, so it is a web app?

Comment: @AlexGru, hi! Yes, it is a web app. Actually, my question is not about code (and that is why I didn't provide any). The app works smoothly on desktop browsers and most of the mobile browsers. But I found out that smartphones with multiple back cameras differ somewhat (on all browsers). The app works on them too, but users can't see any camera labels (front cam / back cam 1/2/3/all three) on a dropdown list to choose from. There are only empty strings. I'm interested if there is a way to emulate this kind of devices. If there isn't I'd like to hear any other ideas :)

Comment: I see. But we should check the code here as well, so we can investigate why the dropdown list is empty.